# How can I change the EntityState of an Entity that is part of a child collection to a detached entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I've got a new parent entity, that has `Lanugages` as a navigation property.  Before the parent entity belongs to a domaincontext, I `Add` the existing Language, which set's it's entitystate to `Added`.  The Language entity already exists in the DB, but because I have to add it to the parent entity before there's a context, I have no opportunity to `Attach` the language entity instead of adding it.

How can I change the `EntityState` of my Language entry before calling `SaveChanges()` on the domaincontext, or otherwise address this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the EntityState through the context ObjectStateManager, like this:

```
this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myEntity, EntityState.Added);
```

Where EntityState enumeration is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ...

Comment: This only works on the server side.  I need a solution that works on the client side (Silverlight).

Comment: Can you not (1) create your parent (2) add it to context (3) load child language into context (4) attach child language to parent (5) SubmitChanges ? I *think* that if this is taking place within the same context then your child should get the correct EntityState.

Comment: In a perfect world, absolutely.  But unfortunately, the code is laid out in a way (not my work, inherited) that makes that order of operations basically impossible.

Comment: If you are in a disconnected context situation then (which it sounds like you are), then the only way I know to sort out the problem of EF trying to add an existing object to a new entity is to give your class objects their own ObjectState property (through an interface, say) and then on the server side map those object states to EntityStates so that EF can then pick up the changes and correctly deal with the entities by attaching rather than adding.

Comment: So, I got this working, but it's not an elegant solution.  It is known that my language entites are essentially constants, they are never added to or altered.  I've overriden `SaveChanges()` on the server and trap any entities of `Language` and change them back to unmodified. Pretty ugly IMO, but gets the job done I guess.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment in a different answer, you mention that the language entities are essentially constants.  Does this mean that the primary key value doesn't change and is known to you?  If so, this might work:

```
Public Class MyParent
    Public Property Language as Language  '<--- navigation property
    Public Property LanguageID as Integer '<--- primary key foreign key
End Class

Dim context as New MyContext
Dim p as New MyParent
p.LanguageID = 42      '<--- you language "constant" primary key value
context.MyParents.Add(p)
context.SubmitChanges(...)
```